How to add a filter form in a view to filter entries based on selected entries from a related content type?
I have created several filter forms for content types to filter content based on its taxonomies. In the View Filter Criteria section I can choose a custom field from the content type which relates to a taxonomy, and then in its Settings it shows all the taxonomy entries in case I want to choose one (or just leave it as all).
But when the field is a reference to another content type, not a taxonomy, it does not list any of the entries to choose if I want to. It does end up showing a text field form (which does not work when entering the title of a related entry anyway), but I would like to show a drop down list, but its not doing it. There is no "Settings" against the filter criteria option.
How can I add a filter form for the related entries?


